# What do you call people you hang out with?

Tags: single-word-requests

The obvious choice of friends comes to mind, but that isn't entirely encompassing. You can hang out with your friends, your SO's, your siblings, your acquaintances, or just random strangers someone else invites. Also, "loved ones" doesn't really work either since this includes people like your parents and other relatives, but you don't really hang out with them.

Not really sure how to define hang out, but a base definition would be people you can relax with outside professional settings and talk about stuff like your favorite shows or people you're interested in.

Comment: Buddies, pals, chums, amigos.

Comment: It's unclear what is the scope of the word you want. How can it include "your siblings" and people you don't live with, but not "your parents and other relatives"? And if people are "people you hang out with", they're not random strangers any more, are they?

Comment: @RosieF Your relationships with your parents and relatives (I meant older, should've mentioned that) is different from the ones you have with people you usually spend time with

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If an informal word (on the same level as "hang out") works, you could call them your **squad** or your **crew.**

[Wiktionary defines *squad* as:](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/squad#Noun)

> (slang) One's friend group, taken collectively; one's peeps.

[The Free Dictionary defines *crew* as:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/crew)

> (Slang) A group of people, especially friends or associates.

The terms are both typically more general than just "one's friends," so either would be appropriate in this instance.

Comment: This is literally perfect and so obvious, how did I not see this. Posse would also work too

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more natural and perhaps more respectful to refer to people by your actual relation instead of trying to group them into one category (friends and family, wife and work acquittances etc.).

However, if one word that can be used to describe all the ***people*** you socialize with, then how about "my ***people***"?

It is slang usage and probably isn't appropriate, but https://www.urbandictionary.com/ has the following definition for it.

> My people
> Those from whom I come, belong socially, or ethnically, have much in common, or do similar things alike!

Whatever word you use, I think there will be unnatural examples. You wouldn't call acquaintances "my people", "crew", or "posse", and if I called my wife my "squad" she would probably divorce me.